# How can I add a consecutively numbered prefix to file names using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using the following script to rename files in a directory. It works to rename the files as BX1, BX2 … BXn. However, I would like it to prepend this newname to the existing filename.

```
$i = 1; dir *.txt | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('BX{0:D4}.txt' -f $i++)}
```

In other words I want

- Apple.txt
- Dog.txt
- Zebra.txt

To appear as

1. BX001 Apple.txt
2. BX002 Dog.txt
3. BX003 Zebra.tx

I tried changing to `'BX{0:D4}.txt'+ $_.Name` or `'BX{0:D4}.txt'+ $_.FullName` or `'BX{0:D4}.txt'+ $_.Directory.Name` but then I receive message that says Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.

Comment: Oh, you are right - you wanted BX before the filename. Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `BaseName` property and another format:

```
$i = 1; dir *.txt | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('BX{1:D4} {0}.txt' -f $_.BaseName, $i++)}
```

Also, you can use the `-Begin` Parameter of the [ForEach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet to initialize your variable:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin{ $i = 1; } -Process { 
        Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('BX{1:D4} {0}.txt' -f $_.BaseName, $i++)
    }
```